# Transform the array after operations

Tags: matrices, algorithms

Given an array A of n numbers we can perform 3 operations on its array elements.Their are n operations in total and ith operation is to be applied on elements from ith index to last element of the array.

```
1.Reverse(R) : Reverse the elements from A[i..n]
2.Add(A) : Add X to each element from A[i..n]
3.Multiply(M) : Multiply Y to each element from A[i..n]
```

Note : In 2nd and 3rd operation all calculations done modulo Z.

I need to find final array after nth operation is done.

EXAMPLE : Say n=3 and array has 3 elements [1,1,1] and lets X=2 ,Y=3 , Z=1000 .If sequence of operation is ARM which means 1st operation is Add,2nd operation is Reverse and 3rd one is Multiply.Then resultant array after final operation will be [3,3,9].

I need to calculate this array in efficient manner.Please help as A[i],X,Y,Z can be very large